# Preventing multiple form submit with reCapcha v3

Tags: javascript, php

I am using recaptcha V3 in my contact form. It's validating form perfectly but i would like to prevent form being submitted multiple times. I tried many scripts and none of them worked for me. Does anybody solved this problem? Here is my submitt button code:

```
<button class="g-recaptcha btn btn-wycena" id="form-btn" name="send-message" data-sitekey="SITEKEY" data-callback='onSubmit'>Send</button>
```

I found a solution, it's preaty simple, and working perfectly for me. I added setTImeout function to disable button. Maybe it will be usefull for somebody.

```
function onSubmit(token) {
        document.getElementById("message-form").submit();

        setTimeout(function enableBtn(){
        document.getElementById("form-btn").disabled = true;}, 100);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear **Robert** try this one i hope this will solve your problem :) if this will not solve your problem i will suggest you another.

```
<button class="g-recaptcha btn btn-wycena" id="form-btn" name="send-message" data-sitekey="SITEKEY" data-callback='onSubmit'>Send</button>
    
<script>
function onSubmit(token) {
            document.getElementById("message-form").submit();
         $("#form-btn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#form-btn").removeAttr("disabled");      
            }, 3000);
    }

</script>
```